# Swift 2: !, ? -" Value of optional type "..." not unwrapped"

Tags: swift, swift2

> Value of optional type "..." not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Can someone explain me what this error message exactly means? When should I use '?' and when '!'?

Comment: Swift Optionals: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`obj?.fn()` calls `fn` member function if the object isn't null, otherwise doesn't do anything.

`obj!.fn()` on the other hand asserts that `obj` isn't null, and calls `fn`. If the object *is* null, you get an exception.

So it's a difference in assertiveness: you either ask or simply claim the nullable property of a nullable object.

Comment: As a comment, generally you'd want to use `!`. If you have failures in your code that lead your object variables to remain null and use `?` on them, you'll never notice that there's a problem. Not to say `?` doesn't have its uses, but in my personal experience, they're far fewer and farther between.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Ideally, you rarely need to use ! because you can use statements like `if let` and `guard` that bind unwrapped optionals for you 'safely'.

Comment: The only time I've used something like it (C# has pretty much an equivalent construct) is to print out nullable database fields, since if they're null I'm ok with an empty output.

Comment: @Blindy if for some reason the obj is nil, your app will crash immediately. that is really serious, isn't it?

Comment: Surely the point in Swift is that you should only ever use `x!` if you are absolutely sure - it's equivalent to `assert(x != nil)`.

Comment: @user3441734, what's the alternative, hobble about for a few more lines of code until you corrupt something else too? That object will be null the next time it's used too.

Comment: So if I use '!' all the time, that's a safe bet, right?

Comment: @Blindy this is not swift specific, exceptions treatment makes the difference between usable code and programmers exercise.

Comment: Its a red flag if you see code with lots of !'s peppered throughout. You really dont want to force unwrap things, it defeats the purpose of optionals UNLESS youve for certain given it a value and theres no way it will not have that value. If you are force unwrapping everything, the code is not safe and its basically a lazy practice.

Comment: @R.P.Carson that's the beginner in you talking. If you have no way of gracefully recovering from exceptions (which is what these would throw if misused), it's better to just let them throw and catch them in a debugger.

Comment: @Blindy In Swift a `nil` valued instance (e.g.`obj` above) _is not equivalent to an exception_: hence, it is not equivalent to a failure point of the app that will propagate sooner or later (it might simply be lack of input in a field provided by the user). So using `!` should really never be encouraged, unless you are absolutely certain the value of such an optional is never `nil`. Exceptions is another matter in Swift, and are usually handled by throwing functiona and `Error` types.

Comment: Why wouldn't I be certain? Programming is deterministic.

Comment: @BenjaminMayo if `obj` is set ie it's not `nil` then the result of `obj?.fn()` and `obj!.fn()` are no different right? I mean both would give you an unwrapped version correct?

Answer (score 2):

What is a `String?`. Is it a String that is optional or is it an optional that 'has an associated value of String'.

Only the 2nd definition is correct. To access any member/property on String  or to run a function on a string you MUST do it on the 'associated value of the optional' which requires you to unwrap the optional.

I know of 2 ways that this error could be created:

**1st**

if you have

```
@IBOutlet weak var display : UILabel? // FYI IBOutlets must be optional...
let something = display.text // Line C
let something = display!.text // Line D
```

You will get the following error on line C:

> Value of optional type 'UILabel?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

This is because you are messaging `text` onto an optional, but the optional itself doesn't have any understanding of `text` method, however its 'unwrapped associated value'—`UILabel!` can understand. Therefore you must write it as line D

Having that said the correct approach is to just unwrap UILabel from the beginning and then easily accessing its text as such:

```
@IBOutlet weak var display : UILabel!
let something = display.text
```

**2nd**

```
cell.textLabel?.text = bug.name // Line A: you are messaging text on *optional* textLabel
cell.textLabel.text = bug.name // Line B: you are messaging text on textLabel
```

on Line B you are accessing `textLabel` **which is an optional that has an associated type of UILabel**.
It will create the following error:

> Value of optional type 'UILabel?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

You can go to `UITableViewCell.swift` and see that it is declared as:

```
public var textLabel: UILabel? { get } // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary.
```

`UILabel?` is a property in an optional form.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 2**

Both signs are postfix operators of special enums. Object with any of these signs means that it's nullable.

- ? - is Optional
- ! – is ImplicityUnwrappedOptional

Be notified, that "dictionary" converts IUO into Optional.
Also both enums support optional chaining.

You can get more experience about this theme by research next code:

```
var dict: [String: Optional<Int>] = ["b": ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional.Some(5), "c": c]
print(dict["b"]!!)
print(dict["b"]! as? ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>)
print(dict["c"])
print(dict["c"]! is ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>)
print(c is ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>)
guard let bValue = dict["b"] else { return }
print(bValue)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out.

Comment: Your definitions of `?` and `!` apply only when defining a variable (e.g. `var name: String!` or `var name: String?`). But in the context of the OP's error message (i.e. you get this where the optional variable has already been defined and you're now trying to use it), the `?` is for "optional chaining" and `!` is "forced unwrapping".

Comment: @Rob as you see, direct answer about unwrap, and safe unwrap exist.
I've described for deep learn here with some basic explanation about this marks relatively to variables. So good try ;)

Comment: Yep, this is a fine answer, but to a different question. But in reference to the `?` and `!` referenced in this particular error message, this is completely wrong. The `?` and `!` have completely different meanings in different contexts ("optional" vs "implicitly unwrapped optional" when defining variable; "optional chaining" vs "forced unwrapping" when calling property or method of an existing optional variable). The OP was asking about the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Rob check my original answer, I've underline that signs in context of object. Good 2nd try, but missed again.