# Fixing error AudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm getting an error in the line of `var filePathUrl`. The error code is "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped: did you mean to use '!' or '?'?'".  How can I fix this error?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayMusicViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

         var daten = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Kool_Savas_Auge", ofType: "mp3")
            var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(daten)
        var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, fileTypeHint: nil)


    }

    @IBAction func PlayMusic(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped: did you mean to use '!' or '?'?'"

Comment: var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(daten!)

Comment: the error is still there

Comment: var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: daten)!)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! The issue is now solved. Could you please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: I saw that thank's! Now in the next line 'var audioPlayer...' is the same error like before.

Comment: do  you added try ?

Comment: where should I add try?

Comment: check the answer  update section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(daten!)
```

> Could you please tell me what I did wrong?

[image]

an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the unwrapping of its value . please check this one 
[Swift 2: !, ? -" Value of optional type "..." not unwrapped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587282/swift-2-value-of-optional-type-not-unwrapped)

UPDATE :

for example :

```
var daten = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Kool_Savas_Auge", ofType: "mp3")

    var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(daten!)

    do{
        var audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, fileTypeHint: nil)

        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch let err as NSError{
        print(err.debugDescription);
    }
```