# Optional variables in API call swift

Tags: swift, enums, optional-variables

I have a variable like below

```
let faces: [(face: Smiley, label: UILabel)] = [
    (Smiley(icon: .worse), UILabel()),
    (Smiley(icon: .bad), UILabel()),
    (Smiley(icon: .ok), UILabel()),
    (Smiley(icon: .good), UILabel()),
    (Smiley(icon: .amazing), UILabel())
]
```

with

```
class Smiley: UIButton {

enum Icon: Int {
    case worse = -2, bad = -1, ok = 0, good = 1, amazing = 2
}
```

}

I want to pass faces value to an API call only if its selected so i have below code

```
 let selectedRating = faces
        .map({ $0.face })
        .filter({ $0.isSelected })
        .first?.icon.rawValue ?? 1 // Using default value of 1
```

and selectedRating was passed to API call. But now the condition has changed u can call API even without selecting face so default value of 1 is not required. How can i pass then?

if i try with below code:-

```
let selectedRating = faces
         .map({ $0.face })
         .filter({ $0.isSelected })
         .first?.icon.rawValue
```

I get error "Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" on passing selectedRating in API call. How can i solve this?

In the API call,

let sessionRating: Int

was declared like above and i now changed to

let sessionRating: Int?

to enable passing of

```
 let selectedRating = faces
          .map({ $0.face })
          .filter({ $0.isSelected })
          .first?.icon.rawValue ?? nil
```

in API call. Is this a correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2: !, ? -" Value of optional type "..." not unwrapped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587282/swift-2-value-of-optional-type-not-unwrapped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to securely unwrap your value with:

```
// If there is a selected button.
if let selectedRating = faces
    .map({ $0.face })
    .filter({ $0.isSelected })
    .first?.icon.rawValue {

    print(selectedRating)
}
```

Comment: What if i didnt select any face then i cannot pass "selectedRating" like you mentioned to the API call.

Comment: Then you are right adding "?? nil" at the end. That way, "selectedRating" will be <nil> if no rating is selected. Just handle the <nil> value on your API call.