# Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? Insert '?'

Tags: ios, swift

```
let imageName = "user.jpeg";
let image = UIImage(named: imageName);
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!);
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width / image.size.height;//i get error here
```

This line is giving me error. How to resolve this.

Comment: This is Swift: No trailing semicolons! 

Comment: @vadian i am habitual of adding semicolon. will adapt to swift over the course of time. :)

Comment: Be open for changes.  (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @SrishtiMittal There are a few answers here: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587282/swift-2-value-of-optional-type-not-unwrapped** on when to use which and why. If you edit your question, I will be able to remove your downvote :)

Comment: @George_E_2 thanks for the link :)  the first answer was really awesome now i get the meaning of ? and !. Apart from that,  i don't know what should i edit so i will leave it that way only. Thanks again for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
let image = UIImage(named: imageName);
```

use

```
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)!
```

or

```
if let img = UIImage(named: imageName) {

}
```

Comment: @George_E_2 i already added a comment that the answer worked for me and upvoted this answer, i don't see any option here which says accept an answer. What do you want me to do??

Comment: @SrishtiMittal No need to be annoyed. I was just suggesting you click the `tick` under where you can upvote/downvote, so other people are more likely to go onto this question for an answer. Also I downvoted as there a thousands of questions very closely related to yours, which could have easily answered your question.

Comment: @George_E_2 I have googled for this error and couldn't find anything and thats why i asked it here. Even when posting question it gives hint to similar questions and i couldn't find one. So if you are saying that the similar question exists, do provide me a link for it otherwise remove your downvote.  And yeah, thanks for telling how to accept answers. I clicked on it :) will be waiting for a link or upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Optional may or may not contain a value to prevent your app from crashing you must safely unwrap the optional value using if-let or guard statement.**

```
let imageName = "user.jpeg"
if let image = UIImage(named: imageName){
   let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)}
```